# How to run Graphics.h in Embarcadero Dev cpp

Tags: graphics

I am trying to run Graphics.h in Embarcadero Dev Cpp
Issue : Graphics Program not running despite the Graphics file in the folder
[Graphics.h in Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQLLB.png)

https://gamespec.tech/how-to-add-graphics-in-dev-c/
I followed  the above article step by step but did'nt got got any result [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pgjk.png)